# Autocomplete jQuery not working in webform

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I use asp.net webform textbox for autocomplete. In my textbox when i type any value, there is no suggestion shown. Here is my code in Default.aspx:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtName').autocomplete({
            source: 'AutoCompleteCase.ashx'
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

AutoCompleteCase.ashx:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC01\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=elawdb;Integrated Security=True");
        string sqlquery = string.Format("Select ReferredTitle from refcases where ReferredTitle LIKE '%{0}%'", term);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            list.Add(rdr["ReferredTitle"].ToString());
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(list));
    }
```

Any idea where it go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

please walk through this [link](https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/03/jquery-ui-autocomplete-textbox-with.html?m=1),
similar kind of concept used to get the auto complete text.

Comment: @Mana - Is your issue fixed?